# Style File not found error even though it is in my system

Tags: compilation-error

I am trying to compile a file and I keep getting an error:
`LaTeX Error: File "upgreek.sty" not found. [  \newcommand]`

However, I have found the missing file in my system: [image: Style File Folder]

I am currently running Ubuntu 23.04 and have installed various texlive packages via apt.

Comment: What is the result of running `kpsewhich upgreek.sty`?  Is this a new TeX installation?  Have you recently added `upgreek`?

Comment: It doesn't show up.  I did a little more checking and I also installed rmarkdown/quarto and whatever they use to compile latex (TinyTex) seems to have overwritten my original pdflatex PATH, so nothing I have installed under /usr/share/ is being checked at all.  Is there a convenient way to change it back or should I just put "/usr/bin" earlier in my linux $PATH?

Comment: As a followup, I ran this command, which should list all the style files in a prettier format: `kpsepath tex | tr ':' '\n' | perl -ne 'm-^(!!)?(/.*?)(//)?$- && print "$2\n"'`  and it only returned a bunch of things under `~/.TinyTex`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `mktexlsr` seems to have fixed this and switched over the latex under `/usr/bin`